# PHP: Check if a file exists on a server

Tags: php

Hey; I'm currently using the following way of checking whether an image exists on a server:

```
if (@getimagesize($s3url))
   { 
      //do stuff 
   }
```

Needless to say, that's hardly the most elegant way of doing that... But honestly, I don't actually know where to start looking for a better solution.

I was wondering if perhaps it was possible to just send a request, receive a HTTP response (i.e. if the HTTP response is 200, carry on, if not, evaluate to false); but is that the best way?

What is the best function to check for the existence of an (image) file?

Comment: To check if content exists on an external server it MUST be done with HTTP checks, Not functions such as filesize, as they open resources witch are on the local server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[file_exists()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) then check whether the file really is an image or not using getimagesize()

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if file_exists works for remote urls, so you'de be safer to use this:

```
function url_exists($url) {
    $handle   = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    $connectable = curl_exec($handle);
    curl_close($handle);   
    return $connectable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
if(filesize($url))
{
}
```

That way, you are not triggering GD operations..

Comment: `getimagesize` is not a GD operation (although you'll need the full file for it)